# Unexpected error in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I wrote the code

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('nt_changed_msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.lang('tekparerr').'</div>');
redirect('user/continueregistration');
```

in my User.php controller. However, it gave an error:

> Unable to load the requested language file:
>   language/azerbaijani/form_validation_lang.php

Actually, I cannot understand, if I do not request form_validation_lang.php and I do not have this file in my language folder, why does Codeigniter requires it? How can I fix the problem?

My hook file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $siteLang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        $ci->config->set_item('language', $siteLang);
        if ($siteLang) {
            $ci->lang->load('header',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('footer',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('index',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('courses',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('parsleyvalidator',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('blog',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('instructors',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('continuereg',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('about',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('contact',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('controllers',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('form_validation',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('mailtemplate',$siteLang);
        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('header','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('footer','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('index','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('courses','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('parsleyvalidator','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('blog','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('instructors','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('continuereg','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('about','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('contact','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('controllers','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('form_validation','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('mailtemplate','azerbaijani');
        }
        // cierrors
    }
}
```

Comment: **Thinks magic??** No. Check your config and settings. You should already define it. if no then check places where else it loads.(global may be). as well you requested to load `lang('tekparerr')`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have defined it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in system/libraries/Form_validation.php you see the following line (450):

```
$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');
```

CodeIgniter form validation is not allowing you to specify the language specifically for form validation, and it needs a lang file, so your best option is to create one.

Create the file `application/language/azerbaijani/form_validation_lang.php`, then inside that file copy the contents of `system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php`. Since you are best to translate English to Azerbaijani, update your new azerbaijani/form_validation_lang.php file so that the contents are in the Azerbaijani language.

For reference, this is the relevant contents of the form_validation_lang.php file in English:

```
<?php
$lang['form_validation_required']              = 'The {field} field is required.';
$lang['form_validation_isset']                 = 'The {field} field must have a value.';
$lang['form_validation_valid_email']           = 'The {field} field must contain a valid email address.';
$lang['form_validation_valid_emails']          = 'The {field} field must contain all valid email addresses.';
$lang['form_validation_valid_url']             = 'The {field} field must contain a valid URL.';
$lang['form_validation_valid_ip']              = 'The {field} field must contain a valid IP.';
$lang['form_validation_min_length']            = 'The {field} field must be at least {param} characters in length.';
$lang['form_validation_max_length']            = 'The {field} field cannot exceed {param} characters in length.';
$lang['form_validation_exact_length']          = 'The {field} field must be exactly {param} characters in length.';
$lang['form_validation_alpha']                 = 'The {field} field may only contain alphabetical characters.';
$lang['form_validation_alpha_numeric']         = 'The {field} field may only contain alpha-numeric characters.';
$lang['form_validation_alpha_numeric_spaces']  = 'The {field} field may only contain alpha-numeric characters and spaces.';
$lang['form_validation_alpha_dash']            = 'The {field} field may only contain alpha-numeric characters, underscores, and dashes.';
$lang['form_validation_numeric']               = 'The {field} field must contain only numbers.';
$lang['form_validation_is_numeric']            = 'The {field} field must contain only numeric characters.';
$lang['form_validation_integer']               = 'The {field} field must contain an integer.';
$lang['form_validation_regex_match']           = 'The {field} field is not in the correct format.';
$lang['form_validation_matches']               = 'The {field} field does not match the {param} field.';
$lang['form_validation_differs']               = 'The {field} field must differ from the {param} field.';
$lang['form_validation_is_unique']             = 'The {field} field must contain a unique value.';
$lang['form_validation_is_natural']            = 'The {field} field must only contain digits.';
$lang['form_validation_is_natural_no_zero']    = 'The {field} field must only contain digits and must be greater than zero.';
$lang['form_validation_decimal']               = 'The {field} field must contain a decimal number.';
$lang['form_validation_less_than']             = 'The {field} field must contain a number less than {param}.';
$lang['form_validation_less_than_equal_to']    = 'The {field} field must contain a number less than or equal to {param}.';
$lang['form_validation_greater_than']          = 'The {field} field must contain a number greater than {param}.';
$lang['form_validation_greater_than_equal_to'] = 'The {field} field must contain a number greater than or equal to {param}.';
$lang['form_validation_error_message_not_set'] = 'Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name {field}.';
$lang['form_validation_in_list']               = 'The {field} field must be one of: {param}.';
```

For more information, see: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html

Comment: I did this, now it writes new error: `Unable to load the requested language file: language/russian/upload_lang.php` Should I rewrite it again?

Comment: Why is it russian now, but it used to say azerbaijani ??

Comment: I have 2 languages. It gives the same error in Azerbaijani

Comment: You are referencing the upload lang too, I just noticed that. It sounds like you need the full set of lang files for each language you support. So make a full set for russian, and a full set for azerbaijani.

Comment: Brian, but these errors did not appear before. Why are they shown now?

Comment: Did you recently switch your language setting in config/config? The line that is by default this: `$config['language'] = 'english';`

Comment: It was just empty string before, now I added 'english' , however it still shows the error

Comment: Somewhere else in your code you are setting the preferred language. Maybe based on cookie, or session for the user ?? It must be set somewhere, and where it is set, that is why you are having this problem.

Comment: Yes, you need a full set of lang files for each language you support.